# Only the notification from my mobile app doesnt appear in watch Android wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I am using LG Watch Urban. I have successfully connected the watch with the phone and the watch is showing all the notification from gmail, linkedin and other apps. I wrote a mobile application, to send notification. But this notification does not appear in the watch but notification comes in mobile phone. I don't know what is the reason for this. I used below code,

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_adb_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Hello World");

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notificationBuilder.build());
```

I verified that Companion Android wear app, does not have my mobile app in the blocked app list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in [Create Notifications with the Notification Builder](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html#NotificationBuilder), when this notification appears on a handheld device,

> the user can invoke the `PendingIntent` specified by the `setContentIntent()` method by touching the notification. When this notification appears on an Android wearable, the user can swipe the notification to the left to reveal the Open action, which invokes the intent on the handheld device.

More information and sample codes can be found in [Creating a Notification for Wearables](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html).

In addition to that, please also try the troubleshooting steps given in Android Wear Help Support - [I’m not getting notifications on my watch](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6090188?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)